# Combine two strings connected with a hyphen in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I want to combine two strings that are connected with hyphen like;

> get-form

to

> getForm

How can I do this with using native javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution for multiple hyphens. It capitalized the first letter of every part and adds the rest of the string.

```js
var string = 'get-form-test-a',

string = string.split('-').map(function (s, i) {
    return i && s.length ? s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1) : s;
}).join('');
document.write(string);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this : split string and then make second word's first letter capitalized and then join it with first part.

```js
    var str = "get-form";
    str = str.split("-");
    
    var str2= str[1].slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + str[1].slice(1);
    
    var newStr = str[0]+str2;
    
    alert(newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a combination of `split`,`join`:

```js
    var x = 'get-form';
    var newx = x.split('-');
 
    newx[1] = newx[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newx[1].slice(1);//get the first caracter turn it to uppercase add the rest of the string 
    newx = newx.join('');
    alert(newx);
```

Comment: You missed __`F`__

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "get-form";
var sArr = input.split("-");
var result = sArr[0] + sArr[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sArr[1].slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 'get-form'
var res = x.replace("-f", "F");
console.log(res)
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bbg00v8h/1/) Using replace

> The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.

```js
var x = 'get-form'
var res = x.replace("-f", "F");
console.log(res)
```

Comment: this is to specific,what happens if the text  is `get-input`?

Comment: This code only works of the second word starts with `f`

Comment: yes i am only answer the OP. OP didnt mention any other thing it was straight forward question with a straight forward answer

Answer (score 0):

Added the code which would take care of the capital casing of first letter for each word.

```
var data = 'get-form-test';
var dataArray = data.split('-');
var result = dataArray[0];
$.each(dataArray,function(index, value){
  if(index > 0){  
   result += value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
}
});
alert(result);
```